# Create fronting banner before logging in to SSRS

Tags: sql-server, security, reporting-services

I'm looking for a way to display a banner before you have the option to logon or run any reports in SSRS. In the style of a "by continuing you agree to the following". I know custom forms authentication would be an option, but is there another method that could be used? I was hoping for some method built in to SSRS that is customizeable.

The version doesn't matter, I can adjust what I'm using if there is a version requirement.

Comment: There is no such feature built into SSRS. Would you be willing to consider a reasonable hack?

Comment: Definitely, do you have something in mind? As mentioned, I know custom forms is an option. I'm trying to see what else there is though. Or if something has already been made and is open to use.

Comment: SSRS is mostly built out of a bunch of aspx files. They are stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ folders `ReportManager` is for the typical interface and `ReportServer` is for SOAP\WS.  I've modified these files before, to add features that I needed. However, it made it a little more difficult for my colleagues to support it.